# Infant Cry Detection using MFCC and Reason for Cry using KNN classifier

Tags: knn, mfcc

Implementing project on baby cry detection using mfcc. I referred the github link attached below and it is working fine and detecting if it is a cry
[Output of mfcc feature extraction to detect it as cry or no cry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ok3Sk.jpg)

https://github.com/giulbia/baby_cry_detection

I have to classify the reason for cry using knn classifier. I am not able to get any idea how to proceed further and send the cry output to the knn to classify the reason like pain or discomfort or hungry or any other reasons.
I needed help to proceed to write code for classifying the reason using knn.

Comment: Do you have annotations about the reason in the dataset? pain/discomfort/hungry/other

Comment: I have dropped the idea of finding the reason and now working on segmentation using HMM. Could you help with that?